# How to Write GStreamer Code in Object Oriented Way

Tags: gstreamer

I am working on a project in which multiple same pipelines are started. We would like to do it in OOP way.

We are currently running into trouble that we have to make the callback functions static in the class because gstreamer libraries are pointers to functions. For example:

```
gst_bus_add_watch(bus, GstBusFunc(busCall), data);
```

where busCall has to be defined in class as followed:

```
static gboolean busCall(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *message, gpointer *data);
```

We are worried to have this static callback function shared by multiple object of pipelines.

Has anyone tried this before? Any good suggestions of multiple pipeline implementation?

Comment: What are your concerns? It is a static function. You won't be able to use `this` in this function and you are not limited by the lifetime of the object.

Comment: Just pass `this` pointer as `data` to your static member, and inside cast it to your class type pointer and call required class member.

Comment: Or use lambda (or even regular function). Something like this: https://github.com/RSATom/janus-gstreamer-plugin/blob/master/plugins/gstreamer/LaunchMedia.cpp#L108